# Hiding dropdownbox after selecting any item

Tags: javascript, angularjs, cordova

I am new to angularjs and I have made a demo for dropdown menu. I need to hide dropdown menu when I select one of item from dropdown menu. Its working fine in browser but its not working  when I checked by using  any real device(ios/android), the dropdown stays there after selecting any item.

**html**

```
<span class="toolbar-button--quiet navigation-bar__line-height" style="padding: 0;">
   <i  class="ion-android-more-vertical" dropdown-disabled="isDropdownDisabled" style="font-size: 26px; margin: 0; padding: 0 12px;" dropdown-menu="ddMenuOptions" dropdown-model="ddMenuSelected" dropdown-disabled="dropdownsDisabled">
   </i>  
</span>
```

**js**

```
$scope.ddMenuOptions = [
    {text: 'Featured',code: 'F'}, 
    {text: 'Name (A-Z)',code: 'A'}, 
    {text: 'Rating',code: 'M'},
    {text: ' Most Popular',code: 'MP'}
];

$scope.ddMenuSelected = {
};
```